# Vertical text alignment and to fill its container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a mobile responsive design and I'm stuck where I need to show a text in the middle of a circle. The text will be pulled from a database, so the text can sometimes be short or long. I need this text to start at the middle of the inner circle, and if there's more than one line of text, to let the text to go upwards. I've made a JSFille for your convenience. My #child in the CSS doesn't seem to affect the div it's applied to. If there's a Javascript solution, it will also be appreciated. Thank you.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2orwnfxv/2/)

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.theCircle{
  width:84vw;
  height:84vw;
  border:0.5vw solid black;
  margin:auto;
  border-radius:42vw;
  position:relative;
}
.innerCircle{
  width:62vw;
  height:62vw;
  border:0.5vw solid black;
  margin:auto;
  border-radius:31vw;
  position:absolute;
  top:10.5vw;
  left:10.5vw;
}
.bubble {
position: absolute;
width: 30vw;
height: 10vw;
left: 25vw;

border: 1px solid gray;
border-radius: 20vw;
background-color: #e0e0eb;



}
#bName{


position: relative;

top:2vw ;
left: auto;
font-size: 6vw;
border: 1px solid black;
text-align: center;
word-wrap:break-word
}

#child {position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 30%;
    margin: auto;}
```

```html
<div class="theCircle">
                                
                                <div class="bubble"> text inside the bubble</div>
  <div class="innerCircle">  
  <div id="bName"><div id="child">I need this to start in the middle of the circle, and to go upwards when there is a lot of text like this </div></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "go upwards"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by using CSS3 flexbox properties, there's a lot of documentation about flexbox online, It's quite awesome!

Check this edited JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2orwnfxv/3/

You just have to make your inner circle a flexbox container by adding display:flex; then you proceed by centering everything

```
.innerCircle{
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
width:62vw;
height:62vw;
border:0.5vw solid black;
margin:auto;
border-radius:31vw;
position:absolute;
top:10.5vw;
left:10.5vw;
}
```

It's that easy. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fiddling around with positions.I guess display:flex here would be a good approach here

check this snippet

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.theCircle {
  width: 84vw;
  height: 84vw;
  border: 0.5vw solid black;
  border-radius: 42vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.innerCircle {
  width: 62vw;
  height: 62vw;
  border: 0.5vw solid black;
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 31vw;
}
.bubble {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 10vw;
  left: 25vw;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 20vw;
  background-color: #e0e0eb;
}
#bName {
  word-wrap: break-word
}
#child {
  width: 50%;
  height: 30%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="theCircle">
  <div class="bubble">text inside the bubble</div>
  <div class="innerCircle">
    <div id="bName">
      <div id="child">I need this to start in the middle of the circle, and to go upwards when there is a lot of text like this</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check this codepen reference [this](http://codepen.io/sahithiK/pen/YNKxqB)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you. Your answer works to some extent but when resizing the window the text doesn't scale and ends up overflowing out of the div.
Gerardo Sabetta's answer keeps the text responsive as well, please check it out.